# Spring Cloud Config Server Not picking changes

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-config

I am trying to setup spring config cloud using local file system.

Below is my config on cloud server.

```
server.port=8888
spring.profiles.active=native
spring.cloud.config.server.native.searchLocations=classpath:/
```

Bootstrap.properties on client app is as shown below

```
spring.application.name=hello-world
spring.cloud.config.uri=http://localhost:8888
management.endpoints.web.exposure.include=*
```

I have also created hello-world.yml on class path for the hello-world spring boot application with property, `test: Hello World`

Followed below steps to make use of config server.

- Step 1: Update the config file and start cloud config server. Able to
  see config `http://localhost:8888/hello-world/default`
- Step 2: Start client app `hello-world`, client app able to read the
  `test` property file from cloud config server.
- Step 3: Make changes to config by updating `test: Good Bye` on
  hello-world.yaml.

  At this moment, if I check
  `http://localhost:8888/hello-world/default` ,it still shows old value.
- Step 4: Run `/actuator/refresh` on client app. But it won't detect
  any change on config server.

The new changes are reflected only if I restart the cloud config server.
Is there any configuration issue causing the cloud config server to unable to listen to changes ?

I could see `o.s.cloud.commons.util.InetUtils         : Cannot determine local hostname` INFO log on cloud config app.

Answer (score 0):

First of all I followed the same exact steps you followed and got the same issue, after almost day of search and study on the matter found out the followings,

1. we shouldn't use `classpath:/<whatever>` for
   `spring.cloud.config.server.native.searchLocations`
   because when we use so and build the project and run the location refers to the directory inside the generated .jar file, so we will not be able to update it in runtime.

To confirm this you can stop config server, open you .jar archive and delete hello-world.yml file then try `http://localhost:8888/hello-world/default` you will get default null responses

2. So we have to use some other locations for `spring.cloud.config.server.native.searchLocations` either with full directory path or just directory from app running location

Examples

1. For full path in windows use file:///full-path
    `spring.cloud.config.server.native.searchLocations:  file:///E:\configs`
2. Just for a directory (which will search project root directory if you running from IDE, if running jar then target directory or jar location  `spring.cloud.config.server.native.searchLocations: configs`
    `spring.cloud.config.server.native.searchLocations: configs\whatever`
3. we can configure multiple locations too as follows, `spring.cloud.config.server.native.searchLocations: file:///E:\configs, configs`